# Ethereum Foundation position on the use of the Ethereum trademark

Tags: ethereum-classic

Has the Ethereum Foundation][1](https://www.ethereum.org/foundation) made any public comments regarding appropriate use of the [Ethereum trademark](https://grayscale.co/ethereum-investment-trust/)?

If such comments have been made what were they?

Have there been any public comments from the Foundation specifically regarding the use of "Ethereum" in the [Ethereum Investment Trust](https://grayscale.co/ethereum-investment-trust/) (for Ethereum Classic) that was announced last month?

Comment: I agree that this is probably off-topic for this forum. Perhaps it'd be best to contribute to the relevant threads on Reddit? e.g https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5p44z8/barry_silbert_set_to_profit_off_ethereum_name/